# View Windows-created pop-up notes in PDF files?

Tags: pdf, okular

I am running Okular Version 21.12.3 on Kubuntu 22.04.
I have PDF documents with pop-up notes that were created in Adobe Acrobat Reader, on Windows. When I open those documents in Okular, I can see the highlighted text where the pop-up notes are, but clicking on it or selecting it doesn't open the note. It seems that Okular doesn't recognize the notes, only the highlighting.

Is there a way for them to be displayed in Okular, or is there another Linux program that can do this?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: Can you verify that pop-comments work the way I want in the stable, supported versions of Ubuntu? I kind of doubt that my question is related to the specific version of Ubuntu that I am running.

Answer (score 2):

Show navigation panel, go to the reviews. There you should get a list of all of them.

Popup notes unfortunately don't show directly. You have to hover the mouse over it and wait a few seconds.
In the code, I also found this comment:

> Show tool tips only for those modes that change the cursor
> to a hand when hovering over the link.

Alternatively, in the review pane, right click on an item, select "Open Pop-up Note".

[image: screenshot]